# How to implement CAS authentication for REST API built on Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, sails.js, cas

This is kind of an open-ended question, so I apologize.  I'll do my best to keep it specific.

I have a REST API built on Express (using Sails.js actually).  On the front end, I have an Angular2 app that is served up by a very lightweight Express app.  The front end makes HTTP calls to the back end (API).

No one should be able to access the front end or back end without authenticating through CAS.  I implemented CAS authentication on the front end using the cas-authentication module - no problem.  But, the API is still not protected.

I'm trying to figure out how to protect the back end.  I have implemented CORS protection that will only allow requests from a whitelisted domain.  But, this doesn't seem adequate.

I'm assuming that I will need to send an authentication token along with each REST request to the backend.  I just don't know how to get that token.

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure your stateless API, you could implement bearer tokens using passportjs and the passport-http-bearer strategy. Then setup (or implement your own) a service that hands out tokens (see https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize). You could implement the full oauth2 spec and exchange grants for tokens or a less complex approach could be:

1. When a user authenticates with username/password, then send them to a service that generates tokens (say 255 characters), store the token by user. You could have different grants here for different auth/rights, but I'm assuming a user is a user.
2. Add a passport bearer strategy that essentially looks up the token, checks it's validity
3. Add a policy to call passport.authenticate ('bearer'... to check your token - it will look at the Authorization header for a bearer token then check it against the database and find the appropriate user - otherwise reject (401, return to login, etc.)
4. Require the above policy on all methods you want to protect (except login)
5. Any protected method will require an auth header with a valid bearer token e.g. `Authorization: bearer kj233kj42kdskfksaj_lots_of_letters_and_numbers_ak3k29asd32kad`

I hope that helps get you started.

Comment: Thanks!  What I ended up doing was front-end server issue a JWT upon authentication.  The JWT is signed by a secret key that the backend shares.  Each request to the backend includes the JWT in the headers.  The backend can then decrypt using that key and verify the requesting user's identity.  This works since I don't need to make the API available to third-parties, so it's OK having the 2 servers share a secret key.

Comment: Yeah JWT works great as well; awesome. Most of my APIs these days need to serve a mobile app and i don't want to store a secret on the phone. Did you use a package for jwt or roll your own code?